# Why does Go think that this structure does not adhere to this interface?

Tags: go

Let's say I set up two Go interfaces and implement them as follows:

```
type fooInterface interface {
    buildBar() barInterface
}

type barInterface interface {
    stuff()
}

type fooStruct struct{}
type barStruct struct{}

func (*fooStruct) buildBar() *barStruct {
    return &barStruct{}
}

func (*barStruct) stuff() {}
```

As soon as I try to assign `fooStruct` to a `fooInterface` variable, I get the following error:

```
cannot use fooStruct literal (type *fooStruct) as type fooInterface in assignment:
*fooStruct does not implement fooInterface (wrong type for buildBar method)
    have buildBar() *barStruct
    want buildBar() barInterface
```

Naturally, I can modify `buildBar()` in `fooStruct` to return a `barInterface` and it will work. However, I'm curious as to why Go does not notice that `*barStruct` adheres to `barInterface` in this case, especially since this would work in a language like Java (likely because Java interfaces are explicitly implemented).

Go playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/84zymo-YnM

Comment: See the FAQ: https://golang.org/doc/faq#t_and_equal_interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function type in go is not covariant, and not contravariant.

So to be assignable the signature must match exactly.

References:

- https://golang.org/ref/spec#Assignability

Comment: Interesting. Is there any reasoning for that? It seems like the compiler could conceivably handle this.

Comment: @SuperTron go's type system (and the whole language) is "kept simple". Covariance and contravariance are complex topics (for both language designers and regular developers). But yes - I personally wish it was there, together with ge-cough-nerics.

Comment: Yeah, I've been missing generics as well :(